# Expression for unpolarized electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

Suppose we have an electric field $\mathbf{E}$ given  by

$$\mathbf{E}(r,t)=(\vec{E_1}e^{i \mathbf{k}_1 \cdot \mathbf{r}}+\vec{E_2}e^{i\mathbf{k}_2 \cdot \mathbf{r}})e^{i\omega t}$$

with $c|k_1|=c|k_2|=\omega$

Is this electric field unpolarized?

Comment: Do you forget to use iota? Because that does not look like a wave at all.

Comment: i will edit the question

Comment: this is the sum of two plane waves ($E_n, k_n, r_n, n=1,2$ are vectors) while each is moving in a different direction and as such it has not definite polarization since the sum itself is not a plane wave

Comment: @amiltonmoreira There is still a problem with your wave. The electric field is vector quantity and you didn't specify the direction.

Comment: @hyportnex so every unpolarized electric field is of this form?

Comment: not necessarily, sun  light is essentially unpolarized although it is  plane wave, its polarization direction is completely and uniformly random for it is the sum of waves emitted from everywhere in the sun independently in each location in all direction.

Comment: can you give a mathematical  expression of unpolarized plane waves?